# MySQL Table Column has English values or Arabic

Tags: mysql, search, identity-column, non-english

I have one table in MySQL which stores `clients` information. There are two description info columns like `CLIENT_DETAIL_INFO` and `CLIENT_DETAIL_INFO_A`

There are more than 5 thousand records under clients table.

What I want is, to identify Arabic column `CLIENT_DETAIL_INFO_A` - and it contains English records, not Arabic values in that column.

How can I identify and prepare a list of primary id of such records?

Please suggest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**One Way**

You can identify based on its REGEXP

```
SELECT CLIENT_DETAIL_INFO_A  FROM tableName WHERE NOT CLIENT_DETAIL_INFO_A  REGEXP '[A-Za-z0-9]';
```

for reference

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html

**Another Way**

Based on  unicode value like for arabic range is  0600 - 06E0

for reference

http://www.tamasoft.co.jp/en/general-info/unicode.html

Answer (score 1):

Thanks guys for stopping by, below is the perfect query for result I wanted:

```
SELECT column_name FROM table_name WHERE NOT column_name RLIKE '[[:<:]][^\u0000-\u007F]+[[:>:]]'
```

Hope it helps someone else !